# systemctl Service that runs an executable that never returns

Tags: centos, systemd

I'm having some trouble figuring out how the services work on CentOS. Right now I have the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=SomeDescription
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This will launch a script that calls an executable that will never return:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=SOMEPATH && cd SOMEOTHERPATH && ./EXECUTABLE
```

The executable never returns. When I launch the service, it runs for a while but then exits due to timeout:

```
Job for selftester.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status selftester.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I noticed that if I change explicitly the script to run the executable in the background it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=SOMEPATH && cd SOMEOTHERPATH && ./EXECUTABLE &
```

Is that the correct implementation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The environment variable and the working directory can both be set in the service directly, so why are they set separately in a script?

Comment: @muru I didn't know I could do that. I followed your suggestions and I could get it to work. Thanks!